# How can I grant my aws sftp server access to an Amazon S3 bucket in another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, file-transfer

I want my AWS sftp sever(AWS transfer service) to be able to access my Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket in another AWS account. How can I grant this cross account access?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to [grant access from one AWS account to the other](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) using IAM roles. Then make sure the SFTP IAM role on the 
side that owns the S3 bucket 
has access. [Docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/users-policies-all-access.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to login into the said server and give it the credentials, this is easily achievable with `Python Boto 3`, you just need to install in your server the `aws cli` and login there, if you are going to only write or only read, set this permissions in your IAM profile for such keys